# Add careers stackoverflow icon in awesome CV

Tags: templates, fontawesome

I'm using the [Awesome-CV](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV), When I added my Linkedin, and github icon and URL. Just I add the name as the following:

```
\github{mohamedyakout}
\linkedin{mohamedyakout}
```

It's working fine. Can anyone help me to add URL of my resume on `careers.stackoverflow` ?

Comment: I don't understand: Do you want to add an icon to [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome)? That would be off topic...

Comment: I need to add icon of `stackoverflow` using `fontawesome`

Comment: `\faStackOverflow` or `\faStackExchange`?

Comment: Can you please add a complete MWE?

Answer (score 18):

I'm an author of [AwesomeCV](https://github.com/Posquit0/Awesome-CV).

You can find `\stackoverflow{SO-id}{SO-name}` on LaTeX template. Use this command with two variables(SO-id, SO-name) to display your stackoverflow icon and url.

P.S)
Your profile link for stackoverflow is:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/61689/mohamed-yakout

Then, your SO-id is '61689' and SO-name is 'mohamed-yakout'.

Good luck!

Comment: It's awesome to answer on my question by yourself :) .. But I mean adding link to my (CV)[http://careers.stackoverflow.com/mohamedyakout]

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 8):

\usepackage{fontawesome}

and

\faStackOverflow
=[image]